# Hire Into Category

Tags: meaning, usage

I have some question about prepositions in the usage of the verb "***hire***":

> [Source](http://www.metrotech.edu/sites/default/files/docs/about/administration/Board_Policies/BP-7008_Categories_of_Employment.pdf):
>   Each employee is ***hired in one of three categories*** of employment as outlined below.

An employee is not yet in a category of employment until the act of hiring is completed.  The example as written, "*hired* ***in*** *one of three categories*" seems to imply that the employee is originally in some employment category before the act of hiring.

So, would replacing "*in*" with "*into*":

> Each employee is ***hired into*** one of three categories of employment as outlined below.

, be better, since the preposition "*into*" denote a transition from non-hired state to a hired state?

Comment: **into** is an improvement. Each new hire falls into one of those three categories.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the difference, "hired in" could very likely mean that they belonged to the category before they were hired (they vere hiring one in the category of drivers, one psychologist etc.) while "hired into" means they hired for a specific job description, not necessarily needing the prerequisites beforehand (the difference between the the previous example and this one is that now that they do not hire a driver, but a person to drive them around, thus he can learn to drive after he is accepted)

a very subtle difference, maybe there even isn`t one and I am just imagining things.

I should mention, that I am a student with english as a second language, so take my opinions with a bit of scepticism.